# Can we add an indicator for answered questions with none accepted that the poster can accept one?

Tags: feature-request

Add something simple like **No answer accepted ** *learn more*(link)

There are several questions where generally a new user posted a question, an answer has many up votes, the poster comments something like, "Great that works, thanks alot" and it is not accepted. If somebody new visits the site and asks a question - it may not be clear to them that you can select an answer as accepted.

If no answer has been accepted (and there is one answer) - when the question poser views the pages where it currently states **7 Answers**  add text similar to:

**You have currently not accepted an answer** *learn more*(link)

- or -

**No answer accepted** *learn more*(link)

Comment: I don't mind down votes - people's perogative - but I would appreciate some hint as to why

Comment: It's probably because people believe that it should be the right for the questioner to decide whether or not the answers solve the question for them.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I'm stating that new users don't know they have the right to select one - notice i didn't recommend text 'Please select an answer' -- I don't feel obliged by the `place bounty` link, nor is there any obligation by mentioning that no no answer has been selected -- would ** No answer selected ** (link:learn more) be better?

Comment: There's a lot of things about the way these sites work that new users don't know about.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - was that agreeing or disagreeing?

Comment: By 'selected', I assume that you mean 'accepted', correct? If that's the case, then 'unanswered' in the title should be 'answered', because you want the user to accept one of the answers.

Comment: @RobH editted as per your suggestion - is that clearer?

Comment: @Glenn: Much better.

Comment: There are a few reasons why an OP may not want to accept an answer (none of them work for him/her, for example). However, if the OP (or at least a new user) votes an answer up, there should be something that reminds him/her that s/he can accept an answer.

Comment: @RobH what about the converse - if they accept an answer but haven't upvoted it, a stronger case could be made that there should be something that reminds him/her that s/he can up vote it, if they didn't like it, why accept it?

Comment: @Glenn: Yes, that can be done, too. I can accept a prompt for new users that lets him/her know that the answer can be voted up if s/he accepts it or vice versa. What I can't accept is a prompt to vote up one or more answers and/or accept an answer to his/her question just because the user has done neither, because there may be a good reason for that inaction, as I pointed out in my previous comment.

Comment: @RobH please note that the request I has is for passive information, not a pop up - no more intrusive than the count of Answers - simply a place next to that with text and a link allowing the user to learn more

Comment: @Glenn: How that info is presented would be up to the powers that be. I'm only commenting on your suggestions. IMHO, though, having the reminder there on the question list, rather than coming up as a notification would be more disruptive to the page layout. Myself, I would not be adverse to having it as a notification that appears in the pull down list on the top bar (complete with the updated red dot notification count so the user sees that it's there).